# Не срабатывает ЧПУ

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, request, чпу

Почему такой запрос не срабатывает?
Мне необходимо организовать ЧПУ, чтобы было переходило с http://test.ru/?route=rules на test.tu/rules

Проверяю на https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это называется тупо редирект, а чпу вы видимо неправильно понимаете.

Comment: и тот сайт не видит ваш локальный сайт.